# Differences in bytes from Original file byte size and JMeter Response byte size

Tags: jmeter

I have a zip file of size ~16 GB (16,165,977,612 bytes) in my application, on using JMeter's Http sampler to download the same using REST url with Save response as MD5 hash enabled - i see difference in the bytes displayed for each run in the jtl file.

**Bytes observed in Run#1** - 16,195,597,710 [Difference of *29,620,098* bytes from original file]

**Bytes observed in Run#2** - 16,195,639,663 [Difference of *29,662,051* bytes from original file and ~42KB more than from Run#1]

Can someone please explain the reason why there is difference in bytes from original file?

Note: MD5 hash response for run#1 and run#2 is same and i used non-gui mode for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same files have same MD5 hashes, if size differs the hashes should be different as well.

"Bytes" stands for "Body size in bytes" + "Headers size in bytes"

Slight fluctuations of the "Bytes" metric can be explained by different values of the HTTP Headers:

[image]

However 30 megabytes is way to big for headers so I would recommend checking the downloaded file's integrity by writing it to the hard drive using [Save Responses to a file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) listener and using 3rd-party tools for checking files size and content.

You can also add a [MD5Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) so JMeter would mark the sampler as failed in case of MD5 hash mismatch.